# Change yolov5.pt format to rknn for RK3588 platform

Tags: platform, yolov5

I need to change my own trained *.pt files to rknn format, but unfortunately there is no any usefull information or tool, I tried this [one](https://github.com/airockchip/yolov5/blob/master/README_rkopt.md) , but when I use rknn format detection doesn't work as needed.

Here is example, when I save confidence scores

```
0 0.000694444 0 0.00138889 0 0.254875
0 0.000694444 0 0.00138889 0 0.29216
0 0 0 0 0 0.2954
0 0 0 0 0 0.321042
0 0.000694444 0 0.00138889 0 0.440093
0 0.000694444 0 0.00138889 0 0.8052
0 0.000694444 0 0.00138889 0 0.878187
```